# How to bind an event to a command in a Universal App using the MVVM pattern?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app, uwp

I hope somebody can help.

I've spent some time researching the best way to bind an event to a ViewModel command using the MVVM pattern when developing a Universal App. I'm using MVVM Light.
As a test I'm using the SelectionChanged event of a ComboBox.

I've read a few people that have pinched the Behaviours SDK from the Windows 8.1 / WinRT framework and had some success with that. I have also included the Universal App behaviours SDK in my project and tried the following (put together from Windows 8.1 examples but using the UWP SDK).

**XAML**

```
<Page
   xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
   xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core" />
...
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding InputQuantities}">
   <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
         <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeComboBoxCommand}" CommandParameter="Foo" />
      </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
   </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ComboBox>
```

**View Model**

```
public RelayCommand SomeComboBoxCommand {get; set;}
```

However, the core:InvokeCommandAction isnt part of the Behaviours SDK and i get Invalid Type: expected type is 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.ActionCollection'. I've tried to use an ActionCollection.... but I'm not sure I know what I'm doing with that.

Ive successfully got it to work with compiled bindings and using Laurent's  [Blog Post](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2015/05/using-compiled-bindings-xbind-with-mvvmlight/):

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding InputQuantities}" SelectionChanged="{x:Bind Vm.SomeComboBoxCommand }" />
```

**View Model**

```
public void SomeComboBoxCommand(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e){//do stuff}
```

I know this isnt what Laurent is intending to demonstrate here and I think doing this is breaking the decoupling of the view and VM by then having to reference a UI component in my view model to get the selected item. But I've seen references to doing this during my research.

So how can I get this working using The Universal App interaction behaviours, if that's the right way to do it of course?

**Update 1.**
This is what I attempted to add, believing, incorrectly that I was adding the universal app behaviours SDK. I didn't notice at the time that it was targeting Windows 8.1.
[image: Behaviours SDK]

However, my questions still stands: Why wont the `InvokeActioncommand`work and why is it throwing the mentioned error? I will look at the other posts as soon as I get to work.

**Update 2**
After testing this on my works PC (exact same code as above, 1st example and the same behaviours SDK) it works fine and I'm getting the behaviour that I would expect. I need to test again on my home PC to see what has gone wrong. (Thanks to Justin XL for sticking with me)

**Update 3**
For completeness, after returning home I got the latest version of my project (from being checked in on my works PC) and it now also works on my home PC. I'm not sure what state my Visual Studio was in but it had sufficiently confused me enough to post this question. At least this should serve as a document on how to do what is described in the title. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Interesting, can you please tell me the path to your UWP sdk? Is it `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UAP\v0.8.0.0\ExtensionSDKs`? Also, are you using Visual Studio 2015 RTM?

Comment: Oh. No it isn't. Its `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\BehaviorsXamlSDKManaged\12.0\` - I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Oh ok, then this is the sdk from Windows 8.1, which is the one you should be using. I don't think there's one for UWP yet.

Comment: Actually, are you getting compile-time error or run-time? This behavior works absolutely fine, I just tested it.

Comment: Hi Justin, Compile time errors. The error is: Invalid Type: expected type is 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.ActionCollection' actual type is InvokeCommandAction;
Oh, im using VS2015 RTM Also.

Comment: Since you have a `CommandParameter` defined, maybe try changing `RelayCommand` to `RelayCommand<string>`?

Comment: Ive just tried that Justin, no luck, however:
I'm on a different PC now and i'm getting different behaviour with the same code. In this instance i'm getting run-time errors:
WinRT information: Cannot add instance of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior' to a collection of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88458/discussion-between-neil-watson-and-justin-xl).

Answer (score 2):

We seem to be getting this question a lot lately, in several different variants...

I'm not familiar with Universal App but is there any specific reason you're trying to use an event? WPF/Silverlight etc are designed to be data driven, all you need to do is bind the ComboBox's SelectedItem member to a property in your view model and the setter will get called whenever the user selects a new item. Often times you have to do exactly the same processing in response to other parts of your view model changing it (e.g. in Master-Child views) so having that logic in a single place generally makes for a much cleaner architecture.

Comment: There are things that you cannot or would not do with properties. For example, a button click, yes, you can use a `Command` for that, but what about `DoubleTap` or `Hold`? You will need a way to attach events to a `Comand`, `InvokeCommandAction` is one of them. It's very MVVM too.

Comment: @Justin: true, but even in those cases you're still binding to a property...you're usually just binding an attached property that calls an event handler explicitly, and you wind up losing certain functionality in the process. It's an extra layer sitting on top of the underlying data-binding mechanism which in most cases isn't actually needed.

Comment: Yes, `Command` is a property, I should be more specific. But what I was trying to say is that in many cases you simply cannot ignore event binding, hence the question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: [MVVM EventBinding Library](http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?page_id=1203) ,explains about MVVM EventBinding. This purely decouples the View & View model & pass only the arguements to the command.

Comment: Hi Nikita, that link refers to WPF and Silverlight. I'm looking for the correct way to implement similar behaviour in the UWP. Preferably without relying on a 3rd party lib such as in your link but instead on Microsoft's Behaviours SDK, to which I'm learning isn't yet available in UWP.

Comment: did you checked this link (not sure but might help): http://reflectionit.nl/Blog/2013/windows-8-xaml-tips-creating-blend-behaviors

Comment: I checked many, many blog posts to get the working example above. But thank you for that one, it certainly is meaningful in the context of this question.